# On back return to first activity and not its parent

Tags: android, android-activity, android-navigation

I have an activity A that once the user presses a button it opens activity B.
I do that using:

```
startActivity(intent)  
finish()
```

The user in Activity B has the option to click on an item and navigate to activity C or press the back button.
Problem:
When pressing the back button, I don't go to Activity A but to its parent.
How can I make sure that on back navigation I go to Activity A, while if the user clicks on an item in Activity B they end up in Activity C?

Comment: Remove the `finish()`

Comment: @SagarBalyan: Doesn't that mean that from Activity C on back I go to activity A? I would ideally go to A only on back from B. While on back from C go to A's parent

Comment: From C, you will get to B, and from you will get to B if you press back button. Do you want something else?

Comment: @SagarBalyan: I want from C to go to the A's parent. And from B to A on back button

Comment: Then refer to @Raj answer.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have 4 Activities : A , B , C and D.
User goes from A -> B -> C ,  i.e. from Activity C user goes to B onBackPress and then A.
But if user goes A -> B -> C -> D, here onBackPress user goes to Activity A.

To implement this you can follow this approach

1. Start `Activity B` from `Activity A` - without calling `finish()`
2. Start `Activity C` from `Activity B` - without calling `finish()`

> Here you backpress works fine as each Activity is in stack

3. Start `Activity D` from `Activity C` - without calling `finish()` /or call `finish()` doesn't matter in this case , as user never goes back to `Activity C`.
4. OnBackpress() of `Activity D`, override the method (`onBackPress()`), and start a new `Activity A` with clear the backstack (`intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);`  )

Or for `Activity A` you make play with [launch modes](https://medium.com/mindorks/android-launch-mode-787d28952959), Make Activity A `SingleTask` so when you again start `Activity A` from `Activity D`, same instance of Activity A will be called clearing all tasks(activites) at top

Answer (score 0):

Just add

```
startActivity(intent)
```

Don't call `Finish()` While redirect to Activity B. It will resolve your back navigation problem.

Comment: Doesn't that mean that from Activity C on back I go to activity A? I would ideally go to A only on back from B. While on back from C go to A's parent

Answer (score 0):

override onBackPressed() method

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        //Set your intent
        Intent intent = new Intent(currentAct.class,Activity A);
        startActivity(intent);

    }
```

Comment: Correction: `Intent intent = new Intent(currentAct.this,Activity_A.class);`